# One Number in the Set $\{0,1,...,m−1\}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $m$ be a natural number $>1$. Every natural number is congruent modulo $m$ to exactly one number in the set $\{0,1,...,m−1\}$.

Where can I find a concrete proof of this theorem?

Comment: As $0,1\ldots ,m-1$ are the only possible remainders upon division by $m$, the result follows by definition does it not?

Comment: Any number theory book

Comment: Euclidean division answers that, as pointed by the answers. Without even knowing about Euclidean division, it is still obvious that there is at most one such number. Assume $0\leq x<y\leq m-1$ and $x$ and $y$ are both congruent to your number. Then $x\equiv y$ mod $m$, which means $m$ divides $y-x$. But $0<y-x<m$. Is this possible? For the existence, start with your natural number $n\geq 0$. If $n\leq m-1$, you're done. If not, substract $m$ as many times as needed to obtain a number $\leq m-1$. That is $n-(k+1)m$ with $k=\min\{l\;;\;n-lm\geq m\}$.

Answer (score 4):

This is basically just the so-called division algorithm, which isn’t an algorithm at all: it’s the theorem that if $n$ and $m$ are integers, and $m\ne 0$, then there are unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $n=mq+r$ and $0\le r<|m|$. Clearly if $n=mq+r$, then $n\equiv r\pmod m$.

You can find a proof [here](http://planetmath.org/proofofdivisionalgorithmforintegers) or in just about any abstract algebra or number theory text.

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the division algorithm. A proof can be found in most elementary number theory texts. See Silverman's *A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory* for example.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: to prove this result you can use the Euclidean division. And the fact that every number is congruent modulo $m$ to exactly one number in the set $\{0,1, \dots,m-1 \}$ follows from the uniqueness of the remainder and the fact that it must be less than $m$ to be a "valid" remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m \ge 1$.  Here is a proof that every natural number $n$ is congruent modulo $m$ to exactly one number in the interval $\{0,\ldots,m-1\}$.  First notice that no two of the numbers $0,\ldots,m-1$ are congruent modulo $m$, because adding a nonzero multiple of $m$ to any number in this interval results in a number outside the interval.

Therefore it suffices to prove that every natural number $n$ is congruent modulo $m$ to at least one number in this interval.  We can show this by induction on $n$.
The base case $n = 0$ holds because $0$ is congruent to itself.

For the induction step, assume that $n$ is congruent to $k \in \{0,\ldots,m-1\}$.  If $k < m-1$, then $n+1$ is congruent to $k+1$, which lies in this interval.  If $k = m-1$ then $n+1$ is congruent to $0$, which also lies in this interval.